# How can i display data in given format

Tags: gridview

[image]

Hi,
I want to display data in format as given in image.
I am using GridView to display data.
FirstName,LastName etc. columns are binding to Grid.
But I have to add row above Header with two columns "Who has changed "Job Role"" and WorkGroup.
How can i do it.

Comment: I just want to format gridview header in the given format.don't confuse about MS Access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from following question in stack overflow

ASP.NET GridView second header row to span main header row